# Detect <,>, >=,<= operators in Ruby and use in .where method (no active record)

Tags: ruby, activemodel

In plain ruby (no active record)

```
def where(options)
end
```

The options could be key, value pair, or a comparison like >,<,>=, <=

If I have an array of records...

```
record = Struct.new(:name, :address, :amount)
```

How to I test which and filter on those?

For example, if I do:

```
.where(:amount > 5)
```

vs

```
.where(name: 'John')
```

or even

```
.where(name: 'John', :amount>5)
```

I would like it to return the items that meet the requirement.

```
array_of_records.select { |record| record.name == 'John'  } 
array_of_records.select { |record| record.amount > 5  }
```

I was thinking I need something like this, but not sure where to start.

```
option_type(option)
   case option
   when keyvalue?(option)
   when gtr_then?(option)
   when gtr_then_eql?(option)
   when less_then?(option)
   when less_then_eql?(option)
   end
end


keyvalue?(mykey: 5)
   # Code detects key value pair
   # Return true
end

gtr_then?(mykey > 5)
   # Code detects > operator
   # Return True
end

less_then?(mykey < 5)
   # Code detects < operator
   # Return true
end

less_then_eql?(mykey <= 5)
   # Code detects <= operator
   # return true
end

gtr_then_eql?(mykey >= 5)
   # Code detects >= operator
   # return true
end
```

Comment: `.where(:amount > 5)` raises an error in Ruby. IMO you first have to define a syntax or DSL that is able to express what you want and is readable by Ruby.

Comment: Well, you could monkey-patch the `Symbol` class to introduce a `>` method, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: `array_of_records.select { |record| record.name = 'John'  }` does not make sense, you can use `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 2):

Well, even ActiveRecord uses string representation for such an option:
`.where('amount > 5')`
It might be easier for AR to do so, as it can pass directly to the database. In your case, you'll have to parse the string, find the operator and the operands, and perform the action.

But there is an alternative (supported by AR as well), to use ranges. With endless ranges in Ruby 2.6 is quite easy:
`.where(amount: 5..)`
while in previous versions you can do it with `.where(amount: 5..Float::INFINITY)`

Then you just need to check if the argument is a range and if it covers the value (make sure to use `cover?` and not `include?` as you don't want to iterate over an infinite array)

Comment: Quite clever! Though I don't know that I'd want to have to support it later... :)

Answer (score 2):

Mixing @Richard-Degenne's comment and Maxim's answer, you could write something like this.

It's probably not a good idea to define :>, :<, ... for `Symbol` so you might want to use [Refinements](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html). Use at your own risk!

```
class Record
  attr_reader :name, :address, :amount
  def initialize(name, address, amount)
    @name = name
    @address = address
    @amount = amount
  end

  def to_s
    [name, address, amount].join(' ')
  end

  def inspect
    to_s
  end
end

module Enumerable
  def where(query)
    select do |record|
      case query
      when Hash
        query.all? do |key, pattern|
          pattern === record.send(key)
        end
      when WhereComparator
        query.match? record
      end
    end
  end
end

class WhereComparator
  def initialize(sym, operator, other)
    @sym = sym
    @operator = operator
    @other = other
  end

  def match?(record)
    record.send(@sym).send(@operator, @other)
  end
end

module MyWhereSyntax
  refine Symbol do
    [:<, :<=, :==, :>=, :>].each do |operator|
      define_method operator do |other|
        WhereComparator.new(self, operator, other)
      end
    end
  end
end

using MyWhereSyntax

records = [
  Record.new('John', 'a', 7),
  Record.new('Jack', 'b', 12),
  Record.new('Alice', 'c', 19),
  Record.new('John', 'd', 2),
]

p records.where(name: 'John')
#=> [John a 7, John d 2]
p records.where(name: 'John', amount: 2)
#=> [John d 2]
p records.where(name: 'John').where(:amount > 5)
#=> [John a 7]
p records.where(name: 'John').where(:amount > 7)
#=> []
p records.where(:amount > 8).where(:address <= 'c')
#=> [Jack b 12, Alice c 19]
p records.where(name: /^J...$/)
#=> [John a 7, Jack b 12, John d 2]
```

As a bonus, you can write:

```
long_enough = :size > 7
# => #<WhereComparator:0x00000000017072f8 @operator=:>, @other=7, @sym=:size>
long_enough.match? 'abcdefgh'
# => true
long_enough.match? 'abc':
# => false
```